Error when connect to ArcGIS Server with Python API
I am working with ArcGIS Python API and trying to connect to a local server with the code:
gis = GIS(url="https://localhost:6443/arcgis", username="**", password="**", verify_cert=False)

But I get the error:
*SSLError: Please set verify_cert=False due to encountered SSL error: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=6443): 
    Max retries exceeded with url: /arcgis/sharing/rest/info?f=json (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError("The certificate's CN name does not match the passed value.")))

As the error message ask, I have added the verify_cert=False, and by reading solutions from other forum, I also install the urllib3==1.25.11. But I still get that error. How can I solve this error?

As arcgis.gis module | ArcGIS API for Python states, "The GIS class is representative of a single ArcGIS Online organization or an ArcGIS Enterprise deployment."  You are trying to connect directly to ArcGIS Server using the wrong class.  You need to be using arcgis.gis.server module | ArcGIS API for Python

Ah yes, it works. Sorry, I should read the document carefully..
